# Qt - connecting in class - something wrong - this

Tags: c++, qt, memory, this, connect

```
connect(from_file, SIGNAL(triggered()), MyQPlainTextEdit,
SLOT(on_pushButton_clicked()));
```

expected primary-expression before ',' token ..

Why this doesn't work? When I use `this`, it works (in my case `this` is `MyQPlainTextEdit(0x20429230, name="plainTextEdit")`), so why this doesn't work?

```
                                                         ^
```

Comment: Because `MyPlainTextEdit` is a class, and you can't connect to a class, only to object. Also, it should be _pointer_ to object. In the case of `this`, it's right.

Answer (score 0):

The receiver should be an object rather than class name.

So, the code should be:

```
MyQPlainTextEdit *edit = new MyQPlainTextEdit(this);
connect(from_file, SIGNAL(triggered()), edit, SLOT(on_pushButton_clicked()));
```

Comment: He calls it from inside of MyQPlainTextEdit, so it's wrong.

Comment: if called from inside, the third parameter to `connect` should be `this`.